# Replacement tyres for my daughter's used bike

Tags: tire

[image]I bought a used Orbis Jewel 20 Zoll
for my daughter but I must change the tyres Honda 20x2.125 white but I cant find this exactly white tyres and in this dimensions. I found only black tyres .... she told me that she wants pink or pink white or white or if nothing else black but you know how she told me that ....after some investigation I found this Kenda BMX Freestyle Fahrrad Reifen 20" 20x1.95 50-406 KRACKPOT am I going to have a problem if I put these lower dimension tyres and do you know how good they are? Another question is she going to have problem with this lower dimension tyres while she's learning to balance without training wheels? And my last question for this pink tyres are good for offroad?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: White (or pink) tires are unfortunately hard to find.  As to "off-road", both white and pink tires tend to be made from inferior rubber and won't hold up as well (as you apparently found), but there's no reason either should be worse for off-road -- the tread patterns tend to be mildly knobby, which should be sufficient for a 20" bike.

Comment: a search on Amazon for "20 inch tires white" yields [this result](https://www.amazon.com/Goodyear-Folding-Bead-Bike-2-125/dp/B01HOXOS3K/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=20+inch+tires+white&qid=1553863462&s=gateway&sr=8-3) among others.

Answer (score 4):

In the tyre size, "20" refers to the diameter and the other number is the width.  The replacement tyre you're considering is the same diameter (which is crucial) and almost the same width: the difference is only 3/16in (4.5mm). That should be no problem at all.

The width of the tyres isn't actually important for balance, so there'll be no problem there.

We don't give product recommendations, but Kenda are a respectable brand.

Any tyre should be plenty strong enough for a child riding anywhere. The ones you mention seem to have reasonable grip.  The only reason you don't see pros riding with pink tyres is that they're not as cool as your daughter.

Comment: Having dealt with a lot of kid's bikes, white (and pink) tires age generally made with an inferior rubber that does not hold up as well (it cracks).  But in terms of traction and "grip" they are fine.

Comment: Colorful tires used to be common in road racing until Continental came up with carbon-based rubber mixture that was better than silica based mixtures in everything but appearance.

Comment: Also note that white tires won't stay white for very long. The other reason that most tires are black is because any other color will eventually become black or grey, especially on the part that contacts the road surface.

Comment: @Kibbee Which probably won't be a problem for the kid: Once it's *her* bike, it'll stay *her* bike as its tires slowly become yellow and gray. She won't remember the exact bright white tone too much. That is, unless some idiot kid in her class starts pointing out the grubby looking tires...